# Include LaTeX code from R objects into markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am writing up a report where the output gets pushed to a `xlsx` document via `library(xlsx)`. This data then feeds into a table especially formatted with LaTeX code that formats the output:

````
```{r import_results, echo = F}

if(!file.exists("Analysis/results.xlsx")){
  wb <- xlsx::createWorkbook(type = "xlsx")
  sheets <- xlsx::createSheet(wb, "data")
}else{
    wb <- loadWorkbook("Analysis/results.xlsx")
    sheets <- removeSheet(wb, "data")
    sheets <- xlsx::createSheet(wb, "data")
}
getSheets(wb)
addDataFrame(sheet = sheets, x = Results1)
addDataFrame(sheet = sheets, x = Results2, startRow = nrow(Results1)+2)
addDataFrame(sheet = sheets, x = Results3, startRow = nrow(Results1)+ nrow(Results2) + 4)

xlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, "Analysis/results.xlsx")
}
````

[image: Excel view]
After writing to sheet that table data is linked to, I read it back into R, now with all the LaTeX in the cells and in essence I want to `cat` results so they are LaTeX code, but it prints the `data.frame` as a long string when I `knit`:

````
```{r, echo = F, results='asis'}
wb <- read.xlsx("Analysis/results.xlsx", sheetName = "import", header=F)
row.names(wb) <-NULL
wb
```
````

[image: Output]

What is the appropriate way to automate this cross platform integration?

Comment: Why do you send the latex to Excel? You can get that code printed with chunk option `results='asis'`

Comment: I send it to excel as the table is quite multidimensional, such that the current `stargazer` and `xtable` package can't produce these tables which uses `multicolumn`. The excel handles the formatting me in the automation process.

Answer (score 0):

I got the example to work in a very "simplistic" manner. Although I dont think its the cleanest code out there, it does work for what I need it to do:

````
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)
wb <- read.xlsx("Analysis/results.xlsx", sheetName = "import", header=F, stringsAsFactors = F)
wb <- mutate_each(wb, funs(replace(., which(is.na(.)), "")))

```{r, echo = F, results = 'asis'}
for(i in 1:nrow(wb)){
  cat(unlist(wb[i,]),"\n")
}
```
````